# Example for $\{x\}_{x \in X} $ and $(x)_{x \in X} $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation, definition

In wiki I read:

[Linear_independence#Infinite_dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Infinite_dimensions)

But I don't understand what it means $\{x\}_{x \in X} $ and I need examples, and as well as for $(x)_{x \in X} $

Comment: $\{x\}_{x \in X}$ is dumb notation.  If interpreted literally, it refers simply to the set $X$.  Perhaps $\{x\}_{x \in X}$ is meant to be some kind of "ordered set", or perhaps a set allowing repetition.

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of a sequence?  If so, that will be a useful example here.

Comment: Ok, I am familiar with the idea.. but I don't understand..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly clearer way to phrase the statement from the page you've linked:

> A set $X$ of elements of $V$ is linearly independent if, for some indexing $I$ of the set $X$, the [family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family) $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ is linearly independent.

Note however, that if we take $I = X$, then we get the statement from the page.

For the purposes of its common usage, there is no distinction between $(x)$ and $\{x\}$.  The key is to understand that, in the first definition of linear independence, they assume that the set in question is actually an [indexed family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family), which is to say we have some kind of "ordering" of the elements from our set. Thus, there is the need for a separate proof in the case that a set is not given as an family.

In fact: the distinction is that indices $I$ the family $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ are not necessarily ordered, while the indices of the family $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ usually are (that is, $(x)$ is typically used for sequences and nets).